# How to select from a table all records for which there are other records in this table with certain parameters?

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-analysis

I have a table like this in Postgres:

| user_id | project | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p1 | finished |
| 2 | p1 | finished |
| 2 | p2 | finished |
| 2 | p3 | finished |
| 3 | p1 | finished |
| 3 | p2 | finished |
| 3 | p3 | finished |
| 4 | p1 | finished |
| 5 | p1 | finished |
| 6 | p1 | finished |
| 6 | p2 | finished |

I need to select all users who have finished projects p1, p2, p3. (in this sample table it will be user_id 2 and 3.
If I use `where project in ('p1', 'p2', 'p3')` , it will return any of these projects, not all of them. Unfortunately, projects are out of order, otherwise I would use row_number() and select all rows where row_number = 3. So, in my query I need to mention clearly, users with which projects finished I want to see in my result table

As a result I need this:

| user_id |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3 |

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve this result, you can use a query with the `HAVING` and `GROUP BY` clause to filter the results:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM project_table
WHERE project IN ('p1', 'p2', 'p3')
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT project) = 3;
```

The query will select the `user_id`s which have finished projects p1, p2 and p3.

Answer (score 1):

Having

```
create table projects (user_id int, project varchar, status varchar);
```

Then

```
select user_id, array_agg(project) projs   
from projects 
where status ='finished' 
group by user_id
having array_agg(project)::text[] @> array['p1','p2','p3'] 
order by user_id;
```

[Working sample](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eg6RGLRYrgB2rKdB9Bu34F/1)